# How to reduce Unity water particles splash effect?

Tags: unity-game-engine, particles

I am trying to extinguish the fire particle using Unity water particle. Which is working. But the water particles Splash effect is overflowing. I tried to scale it but it"s not working. So how can I reduce the splash effect?[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

## To stop the water particles from overflowing you can do a combination of two things:

`decrease emission rate of particles` or `the velocity of particles`. You find these things under certain modules. Here is the list of modules:

[image]

To change the emmission rate, find the particle system in the inspector and go to the `emmission module`. If not already opened - open it. Adjust the `Rate over Time` variable to a lower value, you should notice a lot less particles being formed.

[image]

Then to change the velocity of the particle system, this one can be change a few ways. And, it depends on how you change it for your water to go upwards. A good place to check is in the `Velocity over Lifetime module` and you want to decrease the `speed modifier` or the `linear velocity` values.

[image]

You may also want to check if lowering any velocity values from `Limit Velocity over Lifetime`, `Inherit Velocity`, `Force over Lifetime` solves your issue.

**EDIT**

To stop emitting particles just set the prediscussed particle emission `Rate over Time` back to `0`. To do this inscript:

```
 GetComponent<ParticleSystem>().emission.rate = 0.0f; // Or a higher number if you want to restart it
```

Also, when I notice your particle system, you don't have to add burst like I have done so in the examples. Just change the specific variables mentioned.

Comment: Thank you so much. And how can I remove the splash effect completely? I am trying to use this particle effect in a fire extinguisher

Comment: thank you so much. It works exectly the way i expected :D